# How to pass image data to Swift MagicWand?

Tags: swift, xcode, unsafe-pointers

The read() API accept data type but how does this read data?
https://github.com/naithar/MagickWand/blob/master/Sources/MagickWand/Wand/ImageWand/ImageWand%2BRead.swift#L51

```
let urlImage:URL? = URL(fileURLWithPath: "files/test.png")

        do {
            let inputImage = try Data(contentsOf: urlImage!)
            dump(inputImage)  //image is exist
            let wm = ImageWand(data: inputImage)

            //wm?.read(data: inputImage)
dump(wm?.imageBytes)  //return Optional([])
dump(wm?.data) //return nil
            dump(wm?.size.width)  //return 0
            dump(wm?.size.height)  //return 0
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Since you are getting the image contents as Data and are passing it to the read method, I'm not sure what the question is? What is going wrong or not working? And if you get an error message, what is the error?

Comment: I have edit my code, not sure how the MagickWand read Data, it always return 0 or Optional([]) and the image is really exist in inputImage variable. There was no errors.